# splitting txt based on ':' but excluding the timestamp in python

Tags: python

```
05-23 14:14:53.275  A:B:C
```

in the above case i am trying to split the txt based on  : using `line.split(':')` and following o/p should come as

```
['05-23 14:14:53.275','A','B','C']
```

but instead The o/p came is
`['05-23 14','14','53.275','A','B','C']`

it is also splitting the timestamp.
how do i exclude that from splitting

Comment: Please reformat the code its hardly readable, add what u tried so far & expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You are also splitting on the last space. An easy solution is to split on the last space and then split the second group:

```
s = '05-23 14:14:53.275 A:B:C'
front, back = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
[front] + back.split(':')

# ['05-23 14:14:53.275', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Just trying to be polite :)

Answer (score 2):

Split the line on whitespaces *once*, starting from the right:

```
parts = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
```

Combine the first two parts and the last one split by the colons:

```
parts[:1] + parts[-1].rsplit(":")
['05-23 14:14:53.275', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun of using walrus:

```
>>> s = '05-23 14:14:53.275  A:B:C'
>>> [(temp := s.rsplit(maxsplit=1))[0], *temp[1].split(':')]
['05-23 14:14:53.275', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use regex to split this.

`([-:\s\d.]*)\s([\w:]*)`

Try it in some regex online to see how it is split. Once you get your regex right, you cna use the groups to select which part you want  and work on that.

```
import re

str = '05-23 14:14:53.275  A:B:C'
regex = '([-:\s\d.]*)\s([\w:]*)'
groups = re.compile(regex).match(str).groups()
timestamp = groups[0]
restofthestring = groups[1]

# Now you can split the second part using split
splits = restofthestring.split(':')
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots in your questions, answers, or pretty much anywhere else on SO.

Comment: Ok. May I knwo why? I have used them previously.

Comment: They (a) have poor resolution, especially on small-screen devices, and (b) cannot be copied and edited.

Comment: I see. I have removed it